# How can I see $\frac{1}{1 - e^{-u}} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} e^{-ku}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

How can I see $$\frac{1}{1 - e^{-u}} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} e^{-ku} ?$$
I know it's related to Taylor series, but I don't get it.

Comment: Do you know that $\frac{1}{1-z} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k$?

Comment: And your statement is only true for $u>0$...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Or, more generally, for any $u\in\mathbb{C}$ with $\Re u > 0$

Comment: True, but I thought that might confuse if the OP wasn't experienced with complex umber. @MPW

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I agree with you. Just commenting for the benefit of anyone who might read this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $0<x=e^{-u}<1$ and use the sum of geometric series 
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k=\frac 1{1-x}$$

Comment: This is true generally for any $u\in\mathbb{C}$ with $\Re u > 0$

Answer (score 0):

Observe the following, $$(e^{-u}-1)\sum_{i=0}^\infty e^{-ui}=e^{-u}\sum_{i=0}^\infty e^{-ui} - \sum_{i=0}^\infty e^{-ui}= \sum_{i=1}^\infty e^{-ui} - \sum_{i=0}^\infty e^{-ui}=-1.$$

This implies

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty e^{-ui} = \frac{1}{1-e^{-u}}.$$

Note, the summation will only converge for $\mathbb{R}\{u\} > 0.$